# Jframe SetTitle as a variable

Tags: java, jframe, title

Greeting. I'm learning to programming in Java and i'm having a problem. I created a jframe with 2 text fields with variables name and lastname and an Ok button. To press OK it suppouse to change the title of the jframe for the variables wrote in the text fields.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String newTitle = name+" "+lastname;
    this.setTitle(newTitle);
}
```

Comment: So who is calling jButton1ActionPerformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, `setTitle()` must be called from an object instance, not from static JFrame.

If your class extends `JFrame` then use `this.setTitle(newTitle.getText());`

Comment: Where is the OP using static instance?